# reactjs: Cannot pass file to node backend by react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer-s3

I'm trying to send an image to backend through form field in React. I'm first assigning the state to empty like this in my constructor class

```js
this.state = {
  image: "",
}
```

I'm then making a handleChange function for both image and normal text fields.

```js
handleChange(event) {
  const state = this.state;
  switch (event.target.name) {
    case 'image':
      state.image = event.target.files[0];
      break;
    default:
      state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  }
  this.setState(state);
}
```

In the handleSubmit function, i'm calling the FormData function and appending the image to it like this

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { syllabus,image } = this.state;
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', image);
  axios.post('api', { syllabus, formData })
   .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
   });
 }
```

Finally, this is my form field

```html
<span className="btn btn-default btn-file file-choose">
  <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Enter Image" onChange={this.handleChange} />
             </span>
```

When i'm submitting this form and checking my 'Network' tab in Chrome console, the formData seems to be empty, i.e. no image is passed. When i call the backend route with a file selected, the file is uploaded, but i cant achieve this from React frontend and image never gets passed. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send header for content-type

```
const config = {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }

    return axios.post('api', { syllabus, formData }, config)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you should have

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...rest of your code
</form>
```

And if you want to inspect data, try logging using

```
for (let obj of formData.entries()) {
   console.log(`${obj[0]} => ${obj[1]}`); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Worked it out myself. First i assigned a default state `this.state={image: new File([''], ''),}`

This is its handler function

`handleIChange() {
        const inputFile = $("input#input-image")[0].files[0];
        this.setState({ image: inputFile });
    }`

This is how it is getting submitted

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const image = this.state.image;
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", $("input#input-image")[0].files[0]);
  //console.log("image3", $("input#input-image")[0].files[0])
  //console.log("Data", formData)
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=${data._boundary}'
    }
  };
  axios.post('api', formData, config)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      let id = response.data._id;
      this.props.history.push('route);
    });
}
```